# How to format double without fractional part

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

The value am sending is `100233`

```
double value = 100233;
string a = (value.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

output `100,233.00` but i want `100,233` i don't want the trailing zeros . Is there any specific way to get it ?

Comment: Did you try `N0` instead of just `N`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are close

```
double value = 100233;
string a = (value.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```